# how to synchronize two topics publishing PointCloud2 data

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am new to ROS and I am trying to do a simple example of Approximate Time Synchronization.
I have following two nodes and each publishes a simple single PointCloud2 data (I am using the PointCloud2 data type because it has header of time stamp), and I have a node for time synchronization. I am following the ROS Tutorial for Approximate Time Policy. All nodes are compiled without any error but it seems that the callback function never get called.
Please advise.

Thank you!

**First node**

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){

    ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");

    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("chatter", 1000);

        ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    int speed = 100;

        while (ros::ok()){

                sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 msg;

                msg.height = speed;

                chatter_pub.publish(msg);

                loop_rate.sleep();

        }

    return 0;

}
```

**Second node is:**

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){

    ros::init(argc, argv, "friend");

    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Publisher chatterfriend_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("chatter_friend", 1000);

        ros::Rate loop_rate(20);

    int speed = 500;

        while (ros::ok()){

                sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 msg;

                msg.height = speed;

                chatterfriend_pub.publish(msg);

                loop_rate.sleep();

        }

    return 0;

}
```

**And my node for Time Synchronizer is**

```
using namespace sensor_msgs;

using namespace message_filters;

ros::Publisher data1_pub;

ros::Publisher data2_pub;


void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& data1, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& data2)
{

  ROS_INFO("Sync_Callback");

  data1_pub.publish(data1);
 
  data2_pub.publish(data2);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)

{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "TimeSynchronizer");

  std::string data1_topic = "/chatter";
  
  std::string data2_topic = "/chatter_friend";


  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> data1_sub(nh, data1_topic, 100);
 
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> data2_sub(nh, data2_topic, 100);

  data1_pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("/synchronized" + data1_topic, 1000);

  data2_pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("/synchronized" + data2_topic, 1000);

  typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<PointCloud2, PointCloud2> MySyncPolicy;
  
  Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), data1_sub, data2_sub);
  
  sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304706/how-to-synchronize-two-topics-publishing-pointcloud2-data/) by [roskinetic](https://answers.ros.org/users/37867/roskinetic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2018-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the two nodes that publish are missing a `ros::spinOnce()` call in the main while loops. Therefore, the publishers never actually publish messages. You could check this by running `rostopic hz chatter` and `rostopic hz chatter_friend` to see what rate the messages are being published at.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2018-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0